# A geometry problem regarding inscribed circle.

Tags: geometry, contest-math

I don't know the origin of the problem. I got it from my brother who got it from his Call Of Duty WhatsApp group. None of them could solve it nor can I. I think it would not take very high level mathematics to solve it, atmost it could take some trignometry but not higher.

---

## The problem:-[image]

For those people who cannot see the picture, it asks the following:

**Let there be a circle centred at $O$ whose diameter is $AB$, let there be a point $C$ on the circumference such that $AC=12$ and $BC=16$. Now draw a line from $C$ to $AB$ such it is perpendicular to $AB$. The perpendicular divides an half of the circle into $2$ pieces. Inscribe a circle in the smaller piece and name the point $P$ where it touches the diameter and inscribe a circle in the larger piece and name the point $Q$ where it touches the diameter. What is the value of $PQ$?**

---

---

## My trial:-

First I wanted to find the diameter, which is very easily doable by using pythagorean theorem.

So,
$12^2+16^2=AB^2$

$\boxed{AB=20}$

Now I wanted to find $AE$ and $EB$. To do that I needed to know $CE$. ($E$ is the intersection of the perpendicular with the diameter)

So the area of the of the triangle    will be $\frac{1}{2}AB\cdot CE$

Making $AC$ the base of the triangle we get the area to be $\frac{1}{2}AC\cdot BC$

So,
$\frac{1}{2}AB\cdot CE=\frac{1}{2}AC\cdot BC$

$20\cdot CE=12×16$

$\boxed{CE=9.8}$

Now, $AE^2+CE^2=12^2$

$\begin{align} AE & =\sqrt{12^2-9.8^2}\\
& =7.2\end{align}$

$\boxed{AE=7.2}$

And, $AE+EB=AB$

$7.2+EB=20$

$\boxed{EB=12.8}$

---

---

## My question:-

Now I am stuck, I think I have gained all the information needed about the triangles. But I can't figure out about the circles. I have no idea how to proceed.

**So I am asking for some help. You can give me some hint or you can just give me the entire answer.** (I have no problem with getting the answer)

*Simple problems can be solved using very advanced level math. I would request the person who is answering to not use very advance math.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $|OE| = 10 - 7.2 = 2.8$. Let $X$ be the incenter of the left circle. Then triangle $XPO$ is right-angled and if we let $r$ be the radius of the left circle, by Pythagoras we find
$$
(10-r)^2 = r^2 + (r+2.8)^2.
$$
Solving this equation gives $r = 3.2$. We can do the exact same thing for the other circle to find
$$
(10-R)^2 = (R-2.8)^2 + R^2.
$$
This gives $R = 4.8$. Hence $|PQ| = r + R = 8$.

Comment: $R$ is the radius of the right circle right? Where does the $(10-r)$ and $(10-R)$ come from?

Comment: Yes, $R$ is the radius of the right circle. Those terms come from the assumption that the smaller circles touch the big circle, which has radius 10, so that for instance $|OX| = 10 - r$.